# Nginx proxy_pass even if file does not exists

Tags: nginx

I have a server with the only purpose: proxy pass to another servers. I have a piece of code below but only works if the file exists on proxy_pass server to make the redirect, if the file does not exists, the proxy_pass redirect won't work. (404 by default)

Here is my code:

```
upstream backend {
    least_conn;
    server cdn2.mysvr.com max_fails=3 fail_timeout=7s;
    server cdn3.mysvr.com max_fails=3 fail_timeout=7s;
    server cdn4.mysvr.com max_fails=3 fail_timeout=7s;
    server cdn5.mysvr.com max_fails=3 fail_timeout=7s;
    server cdn6.mysvr.com max_fails=3 fail_timeout=7s;
    server cdn7.mysvr.com max_fails=3 fail_timeout=7s;
    server cdn8.mysvr.com max_fails=3 fail_timeout=7s;
}

location / {
    proxy_pass http://backend;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_bind $server_addr;
    proxy_buffering off;
    autoindex off;
}
```

How can I adapt the code above to work even if the file does not exists on current server (proxy_pass server)?

Thank you very much

Comment: Have you tried `proxy_next_upstream http_404;` ?

Comment: What this rule will do?